# Capitals, some other letters elevated above baseline in TTF

Tags: truetype, sdl-ttf

When I use TrueType fonts with SDL (and I don't know if SDL has anything to do with it), some of the letters will be elevated above baseline.  With High Tower Text font, capital letters and lower-case 't' are noticeably above baseline:

In Arial, it's just the 't':

But Tahoma, and Times, don't seem to have a problem:

It is consistent between machines, so I doubt it's the fonts.

I'm using the SDL_TTF library.  Rendering is done thus:

```
 SDL_Surface* surfaceToPrintOn;
 surfaceToPrintOn = TTF_RenderText_Solid (ttfFontPointer, textToPrint, color);
```

I never see this problem using these fonts in other programs.  How can I get them to look flat and neat?

TIA.

Comment: This is because of (bad) [font hinting](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting). With texts that small, rounding *a single pixel* the wrong way will visible draw a character different than the rest; some fonts suffer more from this than others. Can you influence gloabl hinting settings with SDL? (As this *is* an option in FreeType.)

Comment: Hm.  I have a strong suspicion this is our answer.  I still can't fix the problem -- SDL_TTF does allow font hinting (https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_26.html) , and has 4 styles, and none of them work very well.  I wonder if this is a TTF problem, or an SDL_TTF problem -- and if it's fixable.

Comment: Jongware, if you'll post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.  The solution I found was to use larger font.  The problem does not seem to be fixable, only avoidable.

Comment: Since you experimented with it: please do post your own tests and subsequent findings as an answer! Did you render at 2x and then downsample the bitmaps just prior to displaying? I'd like to see the difference then.

Comment: No, nothing so complicated.  I just changed the point to a larger value in some cases, and shrugged and accepted the funky-looking text in others.